# TypeError: callback is not a function -

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, callback

I have this code that is a part of a wrapper for Pipl api and i am getting this error:

this main code does a get request and returns back the information from the API

Looking forward to getting helped by you :)

```
return callback(err, JSON.parse(body) || body);
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

What is wrong here? how can i solve this error?

```
(function() {
    var _ = require('lodash')
        , request = require('request')
        , util = require('util')
        , url = require('url');

    var Handler = function(subClass) {
        this.createCall = function(method, path, options, callback) {
            return function(config) {
                if (_.isFunction(options)) {
                    callback = options;
                    options = {};
                }
                path = url.format({
                    pathname: path,
                    query: options
                });
                path = url.resolve(config.api_url, path);
                console.log(path)

                var parameters = {
                    url: path,
                    method: method
                };

                request(parameters, function(err, response, body) {
                    return callback(err, JSON.parse(body) || body);
                });
            }
        };

        _.merge(subClass, this);
        return this;
    }.bind(this);

    module.exports = Handler;
}).call(this);
```

Comment: How are you calling `createCall`? Looks like whatever you are passing that is being assigned to `callback` is not a function...

Comment: I understand, but how will it be in it's final form ?

Comment: please provide a link for the wrapper that you are using, and how are you using it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pipl   and my code is on www.github.com/stalkerbot/stalkerbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is happening because the `search.query` function accepts options and callback.
but in NPM documentation it says that it accepts `type, options, callback`

check [github](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/pipl)

This error means that you are trying to call something as a function while it is not a function. In your case, the problem is that you were only sending one parameter i.e. 'filepath' and not passing the function to be called.

I guess passing callback(map) in this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath) might solve your error

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `createCall` function, you should pass 4 parameters to it, and the last parameter should be a function (which later will be invoked). And it looks like the row `callback = options;` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I understand, but how should it look like?